# Indentation in Latex for Resume

Tags: indentation, cv

I just started to learn to build my resume using Latex. The problem I got is that I wish to align "Thesis" and "Advisor" with the degree "M.S in Engineering". I also wish to wrap the long line of the thesis title and make it aligned with the start of the title.

I tried to use "tabular" for that, but still cannot figure it out. Below is the example.

[EDIT]

A unrelated question. should I instead put the Master thesis as an item on the list of publication? Or can I do my current way? Which does look more professor to you?

[END EDIT]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabularx} % table for contact information
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % email

%------------The below is for set font for web link----------------%
\usepackage{url}      % webpage
%% Define a new 'leo' style for the package that will use a smaller font.
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{%
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
%% Now actually use the newly defined style.
\urlstyle{leo}
%------------The below is for set font for web link----------------%

% For the roman numerals
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\geometry{letterpaper,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=0in,headsep=0in,footskip=.3in}

% Gives the nice lettering for the section headings
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

% Puts the name up top
\newcommand{\bigname}[1]{
    \begin{center}\LARGE\scshape#1\end{center}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{center} % Centering for some reason makes the line under my name in the right spot

\bigname{My Name}
\vspace{-8pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt} % second one is width of line

\section{Education}
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace{20pt} \textbf{Ph.D. in Statistics}, University of AAA \hfill May 2017 (Expected) \\
\hspace{20pt} Dissertation: TBD \\
\hspace{20pt} Advisor: Professor XXX

\bigskip
\hspace{20pt} \textbf{M.S. in Engineering}, University of AAA \hfill December 2012 \\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Thesis: & \textit{This is really a long time and I wish to indent it in the next line, making it aligned with "This". I also wish to make "Thesis" aligned with "M.S. in Engineering"}\\
Advisor: & Professor XXX. (I also wish to indent "Advisor" to make it aligned with "M.S. ..." \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot of pdf output. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you want to have something like `parskip=true` to avoid paragraph indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Johannes_B. Could you give more details on that?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\hspace{20pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{.8\linewidth}}
```

to start a new paragraph and insert the same horizontal space before the table. Also change the alignment `l` for the second column to `p{}` and adjust the width as you wish.

**Piece of code**

```
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace{20pt} \textbf{Ph.D. in Statistics}, University of AAA \hfill May 2017 (Expected) \\
\hspace{20pt}Dissertation: TBD \\  % <----- remove blank space before D
\hspace{20pt}Advisor: Professor XXX % <----- remove blank space before A

\bigskip
\hspace{20pt}\textbf{M.S. in Engineering}, University of AAA \hfill December 2012 

\hspace{20pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{.8\linewidth}}
Thesis: & \textit{This is really a long time and I wish to indent it in the next line, making it aligned with "This". I also wish to make "Thesis" aligned with "M.S. in Engineering"}\\
Advisor: & Professor XXX. (I also wish to indent "Advisor" to make it aligned with "M.S. ..." \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
```

[image]